# XmlSerialization and Attributes - Preventing a Property from being Serialized

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

Is there a way to get XmlSerialization in .NET to ignore certain properties while serializing?

For example, I have a public bool Property called IsValid and its the only Property of the object that I don't want serialized. How could I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the [XmlIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) over the property.

Answer (score 3):

Just apply [XmlIgnore] to the property you want to ignore.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Use [XmlIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx).